# typer-cli: How to use custom data type with typer

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click, typer

Click have [click.ParamType](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/parameters/#implementing-custom-types), for defining custom parameter types, but it doesn't work with typer (Example snippet below)

I want to use, my own formatting for datetime, ex: today %H:%M, %M:%H(automatically uses date as today). Typer already allows setting, [custom datetime formats](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/parameter-types/datetime/#custom-date-format) but it doesn't cover my use case.

This is example from [click docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/parameters/#implementing-custom-types) that I tried using with **typer**.

```py
class BasedIntParamType(click.ParamType):
    name = "integer"

    def convert(self, value, param, ctx):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return value

        try:
            if value[:2].lower() == "0x":
                return int(value[2:], 16)
            elif value[:1] == "0":
                return int(value, 8)
            return int(value, 10)
        except ValueError:
            self.fail(f"{value!r} is not a valid integer", param, ctx)

BASED_INT = BasedIntParamType()

def main(based_int: BASED_INT):
    print(based_int)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

It gives this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yashrathi/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    typer.run(main)
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 859, in run
    app()
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 214, in __call__
    return get_command(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 239, in get_command
    click_command = get_command_from_info(typer_instance.registered_commands[0])
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 423, in get_command_from_info
    ) = get_params_convertors_ctx_param_name_from_function(command_info.callback)
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 404, in get_params_convertors_ctx_param_name_from_function
    click_param, convertor = get_click_param(param)
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 656, in get_click_param
    parameter_type = get_click_type(
  File "/home/yashrathi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 587, in get_click_type
    raise RuntimeError(f"Type not yet supported: {annotation}")  # pragma no cover
RuntimeError: Type not yet supported: <__main__.BasedIntParamType object at 0x7f7295822fd0>
```

`typer.main.get_click_type`, doesn't seem to be compatible with custom click type. But click knows how to handle  `click.ParamType`, typer don't need to convert it to click type.

What would be the best way to implement my own datetime format?

- Would it be good to create a new class that inherits from `datetime`, and overrides `strptime` to fit my usecase?
- Could this be implemented by typer itself? Because it's easy to do this with click

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `typer`, however, here is how you could approach it with `click`.

One way to implement your datetime format is to indeed extend from `click.ParamType` and do all the hard parsing yourself.

Alternatively, if you just want to make some minor tweaks to how `click.DateTime` works, you can also directly extend from `click.DateTime`.
That way you can have `click.DateTime` do most of the heavy lifting.

To simplify your case a bit, let's say we want to enable the user to specify:

```sh
$ cli --newdate today    # which converts today to a click.DateTime
2021-12-30               # Note: below I also show how to return "today"
```

Moreover, we want to retain the old behavior of `click.DateTime`, such that this also works:

```sh
$ cli --newdate 2042-12-29
2042-12-29
```

Then we could implement this as follows:

```py
import datetime
from typing import Optional, Sequence, Any
import click

class EnhancedDate(click.DateTime):
    name = "enhanceddate"

    def __init__(self, formats: Optional[Sequence[str]] = None):
        super().__init__(formats)
        self.formats += ["today"]  # add your formats here

    def convert(self, value: Any, param: Optional["Parameter"], ctx: Optional["Context"]) -> Any:
        # And in the convert, we'll handle our own formats first
        if value is None or value == "today":
            return datetime.date.today()
            # Alternatively, if you return "today" here 
            # you also get the "today" string in your commands
            # when you use type=EnhancedDate()
              
        # we'll let click handle all the other stuff
        return super().convert(value, param, ctx)

@click.command()
@click.option("--newdate", type=EnhancedDate())
def cli(newdate):
    click.echo(newdate)


cli()
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you get click documentation out of the box:

```sh
python3 cli.py --help
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --newdate [%Y-%m-%d|%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S|%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S|today]
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
# Notice how `today` is added automatically over here:       ^
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: thank you, I will consider migrating to click entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class DateTyper:

    @classmethod
    def parse_value(cls, value: str):
        if not re.search(r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}', value, re.I):
            raise ValueError()
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%d/%m/%Y')

@app.command()
def foo(
    days: DateTyper = typer.Option(parser=DateTyper.parse_value)
):
    print(days)
```

When run

```bash
src git:(main) ✗ dotenv run python -m main foo --days 01/01/1111 
1111-01-01 00:00:00
```

If input an invalid option

```bash
src git:(main) ✗ dotenv run python -m main foo --days 01/01/111 
Usage: main.py foo [OPTIONS]
Try 'main.py foo --help' for help.
╭─ Error ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ Invalid value for '--days': 01/01/111
```

```bash
(precodahora-env) ➜  src git:(main) ✗ dotenv run python -m main foo --days foo      
Usage: main.py foo [OPTIONS]
Try 'main.py foo --help' for help.
╭─ Error ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ Invalid value for '--days': foo
```